# How to make parent element scale with child? (CSS transform)

Tags: css, transform, scale

Consider the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>RequestAnimationFrame</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="outer">
        <div class="inner">
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="myscript.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.outer {
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
}

.inner {
    border: 1px solid green;
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    transition: all 1s;
}

.inner:hover {
    transform: scaleY(4);
}
```

As this code stands, hovering on the inner div will make it scale, but it will overflow the outer div. How can I force the outer div adjust its height based on the size of the inner div?

My issue comes from a larger project where I'm trying to expand a div the 'right' way i.e only using transform. However, every method I've tried (using pseudo elements, putting the scale on both inner and outer divs etc.) is causing problems. A large part of this comes from one of my divs having a border-radius of 20px, and this border gets distorted when I scale, so I'm trying to apply the scale to an inner element and force the outer div to adjust accordingly...

It would be great to know if this is possible, or if I should be trying to do this a different way...

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/css-transforms-1/#example-63675dc3 specifies `Note: Transformations do affect the visual rendering, but have no affect on the CSS layout other than affecting overflow.`, so if you want to do this using only CSS, you will have to use something else than `transform`.

Comment: Thanks Bali - so does that mean that this really can't be achieved with scale? I've heard that some companies absolutely ban transitioning anything other than opacity and transform for performance reasons...

Comment: The `tranform` and `opacity` properties get hardware accelerated processing, which is why it is generally not a good idea to `transition` other properties. If however you need the layout to animate maybe take a look at a library like Greensock which will give you many ways to animate layout and will take care of many of the performance concerns under the hood for you.

Comment: @BugsArePeopleToo - fantastic, thanks for the suggestion. I'll have a look.

Comment: When animate element(s), hardware accelerated properties are recommended, though if you need to animate another, you can (and if you need, you need), and in general it won't lag unless it is many/big elements. If it does lag, have a look at [will-change](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/will-change), which is available but considered as a last resort.

Comment: Thanks @LGSon that’s very helpful. I think in this case transforming the height would be simplest, though maybe I can use a different UI approach. Thanks again

Comment: Yes, I don't think transitioning the height is gonna be that expensive performance-wise unless your layout is very complex and uses a massive number of elements. The main difference you might notice is that transform can get to subpixel precision while height cannot. This means things might look slightly less smooth using height. But as mentioned, if this is what you need, transitioning other properties like width/height/margin/... is always an option even if it is not as optimized